# How to render multiple Chart.JS charts on the same page with AJAX data and variables

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, chart.js

I am trying to create a reusable line chart view component that can be fed a variable from a model to pull it's data via AJAX and an action result.  This works fine when a single chart is rendered on a page but breaks when there is more than one.

I've gone through various tutorials for creating multiple charts on a page and can get this working if the charts are hard coded with data but not if it relies on the AJAX call, which is rendering all lines to the same canvas.

This is the JS for the charts:

```
var hiddens = document.getElementsByClassName("kpiclass");
for (hidden of hiddens) {
var kpidata = $(hidden).val();

$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/GetLineChartData",
    traditional: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: kpidata,
    success: function (iData) {
        var aData = iData;
        var aLabels = aData[0];
        var aDatasets1 = aData[1];
        var dataT = {
            labels: aLabels,
            datasets: [{

                data: aDatasets1,
                label: 'Value',
                backgroundColor: getStyle('--primary'),
                borderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,.55)'
            }]
        };

        var charts = document.getElementsByName(kpidata);

        for (chart of charts) {


            var ctx = chart.getContext('2d');

            var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: dataT,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    tooltipCaretSize: 0,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            gridLines: {
                                color: 'transparent',
                                zeroLineColor: 'transparent'
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                fontSize: 2,
                                fontColor: 'transparent'
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            display: false,
                            ticks: {
                                display: false

                            }
                        }]
                    },
                    elements: {
                        line: {
                            borderWidth: 1
                        },
                        point: {
                            radius: 4,
                            hitRadius: 10,
                            hoverRadius: 4
                        }
                    }
                }


            });
        }
    }
});
```

and here is the view component's chart section:

```
  <div>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Kpi.KpiMainName)</div>
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Kpi.KpiId, new {  @class="kpiclass"})
</div>

<div class="chart-wrapper mt-3 mx-3" style="height:70px;">
  <div class="chartjs-size-monitor" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; pointer-events: none; visibility: hidden; z-index: -1;"><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-expand" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;visibility:hidden;z-index:-1;"><div style="position:absolute;width:1000000px;height:1000000px;left:0;top:0"></div></div><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-shrink" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;visibility:hidden;z-index:-1;"><div style="position:absolute;width:200%;height:200%;left:0; top:0"></div></div></div>
  <canvas class="chart chartjs-render-monitor line" Name="@(Model.KpiId)" height="70" width="275" style="display: block; width: 275px; height: 70px;"></canvas>
  <div  class="chartjs-tooltip bottom top" style="opacity: 0; left: 22.5576px; top: 113.333px;" ><div class="tooltip-header"><div class="tooltip-header-item">January</div></div><div class="tooltip-body"><div class="tooltip-body-item"><span class="tooltip-body-item-color" style="background-color: rgb(0, 165, 224);"></span><span class="tooltip-body-item-label">My First dataset</span><span class="tooltip-body-item-value">65</span></div></div></div>
</div>
```

I am passing a variable to the AJAX call from a hidden field in the view component to pull the right data from an ActionResult.  If I use getElementsByName to collect the charts on the page the AJAX call fires the correct number of times but renders all lines to the last canvas on the page, if I getElementsByClassName all lines will be rendered to every canvas on the page instead of one for each but can only be seen when hovering over the chart.  I can't seem to match up the correct data to the right chart no matter what I've tried.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way using an .each function after piecing together various answers to similar questions.  This JS is called for each chart whenever there is a canvas with a "line" class on the page.  Hopefully this will be of help to others.

```
$('.line').each(function (index, element) {

var kpidata = element.getAttribute('id');


$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/GetLineChartData",
    traditional: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: kpidata,
    success: function (iData) {
        var aData = iData;
        var aLabels = aData[0];
        var aDatasets1 = aData[1];
        var dataT = {
            labels: aLabels,
            datasets: [{

                data: aDatasets1,
                label: 'Value',
                backgroundColor: getStyle('--primary'),
                borderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,.55)'
            }]
        };


        var ctx = element.getContext('2d');

        var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: dataT,
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                tooltipCaretSize: 0,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                            color: 'transparent',
                            zeroLineColor: 'transparent'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            fontSize: 2,
                            fontColor: 'transparent'
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: false,
                        ticks: {
                            display: false

                        }
                    }]
                },
                elements: {
                    line: {
                        borderWidth: 1
                    },
                    point: {
                        radius: 4,
                        hitRadius: 10,
                        hoverRadius: 4
                    }
                }
            }


        }
        );
    }
});


});
```